# getJSON complete not waiting for completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="../JQUERY/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script>
function getItems_GroupID_getJSON(ID)
{
    var h=new String();
    var query = $.getJSON('Items/LocationID.json', function(data)
    {
        console.log("success");
    });
    query.error(function (data)
    {
        alert("error");
    });
    query.complete(function(data)
    {
        var text = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
        h+='<div id="getFullItem">';    
        for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++)
        {
            var MenuGroupID=text[i]['item'].MenuGroupID;
            if(ID==MenuGroupID)
            {
                h+=text[i]['item'].menu_item_name+'<br>';
                h+=text[i]['item'].menu_item_description+'<br>';
                if(text[i]['item'].menu_item_price!=null)
                    h+=text[i]['item'].menu_item_price+'<br>';  
                if(text[i]['item'].menu_item_calories!=null)
                    h+=text[i]['item'].menu_item_calories+'<br>';                       
                if(text[i]['item'].image_url!=null)
                    h+='<img id="itempic" width=75px height=75px src="'+text[i]['item'].image_url+'" ></img><br>';


            }
        }
        h += '<br><br><br><br><br><br></div>';
    });

    //alert("h equals");
    //alert(h);
    return h;
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var str=new String();
    str+='<div>';


    for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        alert("hi");
        str+=getItems_GroupID_getJSON(i);
    }
    str+='</div>';

    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML=str;
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>

    this is the data in my json file that i'm retrieving data from

        [{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"1","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Appetizers","group_description":null,"group_note":null,"group_uid":"Appitizers\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:04:19","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"2","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Salads","group_description":null,"group_note":null,"group_uid":"Soups\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:05:02","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"3","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Nachos","group_description":null,"group_note":null,"group_uid":"Nachos\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:05:41","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"4","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Chimichangas","group_description":"Flour tortilla burrito fried in vegetable oil and served with your choice of two sides.","group_note":null,"group_uid":"Chimichangas\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:06:18","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"5","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Fajitas","group_description":"Our fajitas are mesquite grilled on a wood-burning grill and cooked to order. Served with onions, bell peppers, poblano rice, charro beans, guacamole, sour cream, cheddar cheese, fresh pico de gallo, garlic butter, your choice of flour, wheat or corn tort","group_note":null,"group_uid":"Fajitas\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:06:46","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"6","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Enchiladas","group_description":"Three corn tortillas stuffed with your choice of filling served with two sides.","group_note":null,"group_uid":"Enchiladas\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:07:19","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"7","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Tacos","group_description":null,"group_note":null,"group_uid":"Tacos\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:07:41","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"8","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Quesadillas","group_description":"Grilled flour tortilla served with guacamole, sour cream and pico de gallo.","group_note":null,"group_uid":"Quesadillas\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:08:21","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"9","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Burritos","group_description":null,"group_note":null,"group_uid":"Burritos\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:08:46","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"10","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Border Combos","group_description":null,"group_note":null,"group_uid":"BorderCombos\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:09:12","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"11","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Sandwiches","group_description":null,"group_note":null,"group_uid":"Sandwiches\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:09:30","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"12","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Coyote Blues Specialties","group_description":null,"group_note":null,"group_uid":"Specialties\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:10:22","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"13","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Sides","group_description":null,"group_note":null,"group_uid":"Sides\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:10:40","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"14","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Short Orders","group_description":null,"group_note":null,"group_uid":"ShortOrders\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:11:04","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"15","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Decadent Desserts","group_description":null,"group_note":null,"group_uid":"Desserts\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:11:45","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"44","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Soup","group_description":null,"group_note":null,"group_uid":"CoySoup\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2014-01-24 08:04:08","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"51","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Beverages","group_description":null,"group_note":null,"group_uid":"CoyBev\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2014-01-31 08:44:42","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"49","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Drinks","group_description":"Looking for a fresh twist on the traditional? Wanting to brave a whole new concoction? You've come to the right watering hole. ","group_note":null,"group_uid":"CoyDrinks\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2014-01-30 11:56:48","image_url":null}},{"menu_group":{"MenuGroupID":"50","MenuID":"1","group_name":"Tequila","group_description":"Tequila is an 80-proof liquor(40 percent alcohol by volume)made only in Mexico. It is double distilled from the sugary juices extracted from the cooked pina, or the heart, of the blue agave plant. While there are 360 different varieties of agave,the blue agave is the only one from which tequila can be made.","group_note":null,"group_uid":"CoyTequila\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000","disabled":"1","fDateAdded":"2014-01-30 12:19:50","image_url":null}}]
```

When i run the code with the alert commented out it doesn't seem to run but when it is not commented out and i have to click it every time it wants to run. I also seem to be getting this problem SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data and i dont know how to fix it.

My questions are:

1.Can someone tell me whats wrong with my javascript?

2.How do i fix it?

I've already tried changing jquery.complete to jquery.done and jquery.done doesn't work.

Comment: Use `query.always()` instead of `query.complete()` and remove `$.parseJSON()` and check `data`

Comment: i cant take out $.parseJSON(). the data in the file isn't being converted into json format after it gets into my functions later.
I just tried using query.always() and it didn't work

Comment: Using `$.getJSON()`, your server must return JSON. Now you could try to just use `$.get()` instead

Comment: it returns an array on json objects which has a length of one and i use $.parseJSON it converts to where i can use it